# kerning issues - click reads like dick, letter spacing

Tags: bug, design

Using Firefox <del>16.0.2</del> 22  on Windows 8, I've had a hard time reading certain sentences. Browser is normal zoom.

clean looks like dean.
click looks like dick.

**Screenshot if you cannot see it:**
[image: cleandean]

And generally a lot of letters are too close (close, not dose, hehe).
Like ct in 'exactly' in my screenshot, and ce.

Edit: This happens in Chrome as well. But not IE.
Edit2: Added click example, as I've seen this some times lately..

Comment: Hmm, well I'm using Firefox, and your first "clean" sentence looks fine to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey added Fx version. Are you using W8 as well?

Comment: Windows 7.  Does Windows 8 really exist, or is it just a facade of pretty colored squares? :P

Comment: I just updated to 16.0.2, still looks fine.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What's this cohhunity bulletin?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/whats-this-cohhunity-bulletin)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm, not sure what is causing this then. No one else experiencing this?

Comment: I know it's been a good while but still having issues with this?

Comment: @WorldEngineer yes. :/

Comment: I see this also in Chrome.  There's a slight spacing difference between the "cl" and "d" where the round part of the "c" sticks out about a pixel more to the left than the "d", but they do look awfully similar at the default font size.